# how to completely stop all deformation in an armature

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, bones

i have created a simple armature. its basically one of the sticks which you can use to clamp around a dangerous animals neck.

my armature is 3 bones, main stick, left clamp and right clamp. my problem is demonstrated below. you can see as the clamp is supposed to rotate it also deforms (ive tried unticking the deform box in bone properties)

[image: example of problem]

update

i have tried to add a hinge object, and parent the clamp to the hinge and just move the hinge. i was sure this would work and was shocked when the clamp still deformed even though now the clamp has no bonees, its just parented to the hinge.

[image: hinge]

how can i stop this from deforming?

Answer (score 0):

You've scaled your armature on Z, switch back to *Object* mode and apply the scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale*)